# Python App failing on pythonanywhere using Flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, pythonanywhere

I just moved from Heroku to PythonAnyWhere.com and im trying to get my python app work over there.

So i am trying to access the url but i get an error message. When i check the error logs i see this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fl16xbatsxbru36/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-27%20at%2023.25.54.png?dl=0

Since i am new to PythonAnyWhere i am having a REALLY hard time trying to understand if this is a code error from my python code (which i doubt since the same code works on Heroku). So does anyone know what problem could be here?

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- I believe this problem was being caused because our site only allows free accounts to access external Internet sites using a proxy with a whitelist of specific hosts with public APIs.  Paid accounts bypass this, so it would have worked there.